# V93K timing and levels require Resource or dedicated API?

Tags: origen-sdk

I know that Origen supports ASCII file format compilation using its [Resources feature](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/program/resources/#Compiling_Templates).  Are there any undocumented API for native timings and levels creation for the V93K?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do have APIs to [natively define timing waveforms in Origen](http://origen-sdk.org/origen/guides/pattern/timing/#Complex_Timing), however these are a recent addition to the framework and it cannot currently render to V93K format.

The natural evolution of that is that OrigenTesters will be updated to be able to take such a definition and render it to V93K, UltraFLEX etc., but no one has done the work to enable that yet.

So, its something that we have the foundation in place for, and many people would like to see it, but there is currently an opening for someone in the community to step up and drive it forward.

By the way, this same timing API drives the waveforms that are applied by the upcoming native Origen simulation solution, so it is a natural evolution that you will be able to apply the exact timing on the ATE that you verified in simulation.

In time, I would also expect to see the ability to import timing from something like STIL format into Origen, just as you can do with regs, etc, and then leverage Origen to do the conversion to the final ATE format.

As ever, lots to do!

Comment: thanks Ginty.  Given that we currently do not use Origen for pattern generation, I don't think we would be able to lead there for now.  What is the standard practice then to generate V93K timings and levels?  Do you use the Resource module to call the compiler?

Comment: Yep, that's what we do